# Quarantine Mode Not Working in TestCafe. Second And Third Attempt Results are not getting considered

Tags: unit-testing, testcafe

We have a very simple test case which generates a random number 0/1.
It will fail if the number generated is 0 and pass when the number generated is 1.

I am using quarantine mode to run the test case and while calling run I am passing { quarantineMode: { successThreshold: 1, attemptLimit: 3 } }.

**What is the Expected behavior**

Expectation: If the test cases fails in first attempt -> Retry will happen -> If the test case passes -> It should stop since successThreshold is 1 -> End result should be passed.

**What is the Current behavior?**

Test Case got failed -> Test case got passed in retry(No errors were there in logs) -> Retry again happened(Test case passed) -> End Result: Test case failed

Test Case got failed -> Test case got failed in retry(No errors were there in logs) -> Retry again happened(Test case passed) -> End Result: Test case failed

Test Case got failed -> Test case got passed in retry(No errors were there in logs) -> Retry again happened(Test case failed) -> End Result: Test case failed

**My TestCase**

```
fixture `My fixture`;

test('Test', async t => {
     let random = getRandomNumber(2); //It will generate a random number. It will be 0 or 1
  console.log(random);
  assert(random, "hello the random number was 0 and due to which this test case got failed"); // Test Case will fail if the number is 0
});
```

**Configuration File**

```
{ "assertionTimeout": 10000, "selectorTimeout": 10000, "pageLoadTimeout": 10000, "src": [ "xxx/xxx/xxxx/**/*.ts", ], "compilerOptions": { "typescript": { "customCompilerModulePath": "../../../typescript", "configPath": "tsconfig.json", "experimentalDecorators": true } }, "reporter": [ { "name": "spec" }, { "name": "tim-json", "output": "xx/xx-xx-x/xx/report.tim.json", "options": { "addAttachments": false } }, { "name": "html", "output": "xx/xx-xx-xx/xx.html" } ], "screenshots": { "path": "xx/xx-xx-x/web/screenshots", "takeOnFails": true, "pathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/${FIXTURE}/${TEST}/${RUN_ID}/${TEST_ID}/${FILE_INDEX}.png" }, "skipJsErrors": true, "debugOnFail": false }
```

**OutPut**

```
Executing -----------------SampleTestCase-----------------

0
2022-05-17 16:21:22,863 ERROR [TestCafeTest] Testcase failed
2022-05-17 16:21:22,864 ERROR [TestCafeTest] {"generatedMessage":false,"name":"AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]","code":"ERR_ASSERTION","actual":0,"expected":true,"operator":"=="}
2022-05-17 16:21:33,653 INFO [Manager] Ending the test case

Executing -----------------SampleTestCase-----------------

1
2022-05-17 16:21:43,644 INFO [Manager] Ending the test case

Executing -----------------SampleTestCase-----------------

0
2022-05-17 16:21:46,555 ERROR [TestCafeTest] Testcase failed
2022-05-17 16:21:46,555 ERROR [TestCafeTest] {"generatedMessage":false,"name":"AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]","code":"ERR_ASSERTION","actual":0,"expected":true,"operator":"=="}
2022-05-17 16:21:54,220 INFO [Manager] Ending the test case

 ✖ SampleTestCase (screenshots: aaa/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/SampleTestCase)

   1) AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: hello the random number was 0 and due to which this test case got failed

      Browser: Chrome 101.0.4951.64 / macOS 10.15.7
      Screenshot: "XXXX/xx/xxx/xxx/SampleTestCase.jpg"



 1/1 failed (36s)
2022-05-17 16:21:57,054 INFO [TestDriver] ********* Tests finished *********
2022-05-17 16:21:57,054 INFO [TestDriver] Number of cases failed 1
```

In the above output, the test case got failed in first try, passed in second try and got failed in third try. The final result was "Test case failed". Even if the successThreshold was 1.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Write any test case and generate a random number 0/1
2. Make it fail when the number is 0 and make it pass when the number is 1
3. Run with quarantine mode and observe the case when the random number is 0 for the first retry

**TestCafe version**
1.15.1(Same issue on the latest version as well)

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to reproduce the issue. I used the following example:

```
fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

let attemptNumber = 0;

test(`test`, async t => {
    attemptNumber++;

    const value = Math.round(Math.random());

    console.log(attemptNumber, value);

    await t.expect(value).eql(1);
});
```

I executed the following command: `npx testcafe chrome test.js -q attemptLimit=3,successThreshold=1`.
These were the results:

```
 fixture
1 0
2 1
 √ test (unstable)
```

```
1 0
2 0
3 1
 √ test (unstable)
```

Please use my example to reproduce the issue and share your results with us.